# Question about notation in Engelking's General Topology book

Tags: general-topology

In Engelking's General topology book, (2nd, page 36) he states a theorem related to $T_0$ space.

> For every $T_0$ space we have $|X| \leq \exp w(X)$.

What does $\exp$ mean? I know $|X|$ is the cardinality of $X$, $w(X)$ is the weight of $X$.

Comment: Exponential function.

Comment: (intended here as exponentiation of possibly infinite cardinals)

Comment: @AlessandroCodenotti Thanks for the comment, so does that equal to the notation $2^{w(X)}$?

Comment: @user20961 yes, the cardinlity of the power set of a set of size $w(X)$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a cardinal number $\mathfrak m$ Engelking denotes by $\exp \mathfrak m$ the cardinal number $2^{\mathfrak m}$, i.e. the cardinality of the power set.

You can find this in the Introduction (Section I.2 "Cardinal numbers").

Comment: Thanks. It became clear!

Comment: @user20961 there is a list of symbols at the end (510 or thereabouts) where you can find it’s defined on page 3 of the book.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma Thank you for the comment! I edited my answer.

Comment: The indexes are very useful in Engelking IMO.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma Definitely! But to my shame I must admit that I was not aware that a symbol index **exists**. Thank you again.